# Помогите с Newtonsoft Json

Tags: c#, json

Добрый день товарищи знатоки. Имеется следующий код JSON:

```
{
    "username": "xxx",
    "userid": 1,

    "subscriptions": {
        "109634": {
            "name": "Auto",
            "acquired": 0,
            "expiring": 0
        },

        "279463": {
            "name": "Manual",
            "acquired": 0,
            "expiring": 0
        }
    }
}
```

А также используется следующий код для обработки его:

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(httpResponse);

string username = jObject.SelectToken("username").ToString();
int userId = (int)jObject.SelectToken("userid");
```

Но есть небольшая проблема, а именно с обработкой ключей `"109634"` и `"279463"` т.к. их значения не постоянны, а также количество самих ключей в ключе `"subscriptions"` также не постоянно. Нужно получить из каждого ключа ключ `"name"` и `"acquired"`. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто.

```
var username = (string)jObject["username"];
int userId = (int)jObject["userid"];

var subscriptions = jObject["subscriptions"].Children<JProperty>()
                       .Select(p => p.Value).Cast<JObject>();
foreach (var subscription in subscriptions)
{
    var name = (string)subscription["name"];
    var acquired = (int)subscription["acquired"];
}
```

Вы можете запросить у `subscriptions` список всех свойств (`.Children<JProperty>()`), вытащить значения, не спрашивая имени (`.Select(p => p.Value)`), и пробежаться по ним.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше для этого подходит библиотека JSON.net

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
    string retVal = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    return retVal;
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
{
    T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
    obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
    ms.Close();
    return obj;
}
```

Вам понадобятся:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object)

Comment: Сейчас опробуем, отпишусь по мере возможности. Уточню, нельзя-ли использовать так: `var subscriptions = jObject.SelectToken("subscriptions").ToObject();`.